# How to wrap a numpy function to make it work with jax.numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, jax, autodiff

I have some Jax code that requires using auto differentiation and in part of the code, I would like to call a function from a library written in NumPy. When I try this now I get

```
The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on the JAX Tracer object Traced<ShapedArray(float32[4,22324])>with<JVPTrace(level=4/1)> with
  primal = Traced<ShapedArray(float32[4,22324])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=0/1)>
  tangent = Traced<ShapedArray(float32[4,22324])>with<JaxprTrace(level=3/1)> with
    pval = (ShapedArray(float32[4,22324]), None)
    recipe = JaxprEqnRecipe(eqn_id=<object object at 0x7fa89e8ffa80>, in_tracers=(Traced<ShapedArray(float32[22324,4]):JaxprTrace(level=3/1)>,), out_tracer_refs=[<weakref at 0x7fa89beb15e0; to 'JaxprTracer' at 0x7fa893b5ab80>], out_avals=[ShapedArray(float32[4,22324])], primitive=transpose, params={'permutation': (1, 0)}, effects=set(), source_info=SourceInfo(traceback=<jaxlib.xla_extension.Traceback object at 0x7fa89e9312b0>, name_stack=NameStack(stack=(Transform(name='jvp'),))))
See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError
```

which makes sense because NumPy is not auto-differentiable.

**Is there any way to wrap a function written in NumPy such that it maps it to the `jax.numpy` equivalent?**

A dirty way to make this work would be to modify the library so it calls `jax.numpy` instead of `numpy` but this makes applicability harder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit January 2023: JAX is now adding a number of callback methods to accomplish this kind of thing; see https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/external_callbacks.html*

No, in general there's no way given a function that operates on NumPy arrays to automatically convert it to an equivalent function implemented in JAX. The reason for this is that JAX is not a 100% faithful one-to-one implementation of NumPy's API; rather you should think of `jax.numpy` as a NumPy-*like* wrapper around the functionality that JAX provides.

As a simple example, consider this code:

```py
np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

This has no JAX equivalent, because JAX/XLA does not support string arrays.

If you want to use JAX transforms like autodiff on your code, there's not really any shortcut around rewriting your code in JAX. You can likely get a long way by replacing `import numpy as np` with `import jax.numpy as jnp`, so long as you're not using external libraries (like SciPy, Scikit-Learn, etc.) that operate on your arrays.

Additionally, as you do such replacements, keep in mind JAX's [Sharp Bits](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html), which are places where `jax.numpy` may behave differently than your original NumPy code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax
import inspect
import re

def function_np(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)

function_np_str = inspect.getsource(function_np) # getting the code as a string
function_jnp_str = re.sub(r"np", "jnp", function_code) #replacing all the 'np' with 'jnp'
# The line below creates a function defined in the 'jnp_function_str' string - which uses jnp instead of numpy
exec(jnp_activation_str)
```

now you have a new function called 'function_jnp' which uses jnp library.

It's somewhat of a crutch, but it works for simple functions.